# How to start the server after redmine upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, dreamhost

I have hosted the redmine in dreamhost. I have upgraded the redmine to 1.2.0. At the end of the [upgrade instructions](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade), it is mentioned that I have to restart the application server. Could someone please how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.chiliproject.org/projects/chiliproject/wiki/Restart_ChiliProject

Although the guide is not for Redmine but for ChiliProject (a recent Redmine fork), it works also here. Just replace every mention of ChiliProject with Redmine.

There are many different ways to run a Rails application. The procedure to restart the application server thus heavily depends on which one you use. The best method generally is to find out what you run, then find out how to restart that software. The first task can be solved by using a variant of `ps axu`, the second one by using Google.